# How can I instantiate a typeclass at =>?

Tags: isabelle

I am trying to use Isabelle/Pure as a logical framework to implement a proof assistant for a new logic (so Isabelle/HOL is irrelevant except as motivation).

Is there a way to define a typeclass instantiation for the function type =>, something like

```
instantiation "=>" :: (foo,foo)foo
```

so that whenever `A` and `B` are instantiations of `foo` then so will `A => B` automatically be?  The above syntax isn't accepted; it seems that I need a name for the function-type constructor (not just a notation), but if such a name exists I don't know what it is or where to find it.

I am new to Isabelle, so please do tell me if what I am trying to do is the Wrong Thing for some reason.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can define a class instantiation for functions. It is no problem if you use the name of the type-constructor for functions `fun`, and not the infix operator `=>`.

For instance:

```
class foo = 
  fixes bar :: 'a

instantiation "fun" :: (foo,foo) foo
begin
definition "(bar :: 'a ⇒ 'b) = (λ x. bar)" 
instance ..
end
```

Two remarks:

- the `fun` is in double quotes, since it would otherwise clash with the outer keyword `fun` to define functions.
- in this example, you could also write `instantiation "fun" :: (type,foo) foo`, since the definition of `bar` for functions does not depend on the
  `bar` constant of type `'a`.

Comment: Thank you!  For future reference, how could I have found out that the type-constructor for functions is called `fun`?  Is it somewhere in the documentation?  Is there an introspection command to Isabelle that displays the meaning of an infix operator?

Comment: Also, your proposed `(type,foo)foo` does not work for me in Pure; it says `Undeclared class: "??.type". Failed to parse sort`.  Do I have to declare a `default_sort` to do something like that?

Comment: If you're in Pure, try `"{}"` instead of `type`.

Comment: @MikeShulman, to have found the name of the type constructor yourself, you could have typed ``term ‹λx. x›`` into an Isabelle/jEdit buffer.  This will display the type of the identity function in the Output pane.  Then, hold down Ctrl and hover over the function space arrow.  A popup should appear telling you that the type constructor is called "fun".  Alternatively, Ctrl-Right Clicking on the function space arrow will take you to the point of definition.